Korean fantasy novel where the main character, male, wears gloves all the time
So my sister is a real gatekeeper
She tells me about novels ALL THE TIME, but will never tell me titles.
In this specific novel, the male lead wears gloves all the time. He ends up dying, after helping everyone, and his companions want to bring back to life, even though he's happy with death... 100% a fantasy. Apparently, he's a magic professor of sorts..? There is a 'weird' part where a student of his 'likes him'. But this is justified because she's some immortal or whatever. This is all the information I have.
I am SO sorry this is really vague... I am really appreciative for any leads!!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So your sister is so mean she won't even tell you the title if you ask?  When would this have been written?  How are they planning to bring him back?

@DavidW
I am so sorry! I don't know :(
I do know that there was at least 60 chapters when she last read it, and she read it three years ago...
